# grep split and match

Tags: regex, bash, file, split, grep

I need to parse a CHANGELOG in [Keep a changelog format](https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.0.0/) with grep (or awk, etc in shell/bash) and get the last version (the first one after [Unreleased] tag).

It means, split this file with block '\n## ', ignore the first ([Unreleased]) and get the second (if exists).

With nodeJS, it's very easy and readable `CHANGELOG.split(/\n## /)[2];`
But I can't make it work with grep ... `grep -zoP -m 1 "(\n## .*)(\n## .*)?(\n## )?" CHANGELOG.md`

I can't make the regex match group with multiline even using `(.|\n)+`
Since I'm on it since few days and trying again and again, the [Machine Learning](http://regex.inginf.units.it/) found this `##(?:[^be]+[^#]*###)+[^#]*` but, it looks like too heavy for just "block split with `\n##` ".

```
# Changelog
All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.

The format is based on [Keep a Changelog](https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.0.0/),
and this project adheres to [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html).

## [Unreleased]

## [1.0.0] - 2017-06-20
### Added
{...}

### Changed
{...}

### Removed
{...}

## [0.3.0] - 2015-12-03
{...}
```

I need to capture the block:

```
## [1.0.0] - 2017-06-20
### Added
{...}

### Changed
{...}

### Removed
{...}
```

## UPDATE #1

I found one working (see in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1Anwxh/3)) with `(?=\n## .*?)(\n## .*?)(?=\n## |$)` and now, just need to print `Match 2`

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Toto answer that help me go near the solution.

Here's how I end up:

`perl -0777 -ane '/## \[Unreleased][\s\S]+?\K(\n## [\s\S]+?)(?=\n## |$)/ && print$&' CHANGELOG.md`

Answer (score 1):

This perl one-liner does the job, it reads the file in “slurp” mode and prints the data you're looking for:

```
perl -0777 -ane '/## \[Unreleased]\R\R\K##[\s\S]+(?=## \[\d)/ && print$&' logfile
## [1.0.0] - 2017-06-20
### Added
{...}

### Changed
{...}

### Removed
{...}
```

**Explanation:**

```
/                       # regex delimiter
    ## \[Unreleased]        # literally
    \R\R                    # 2 linebreak
    \K                      # forget all we have seen until this position
    ##[\s\S]+               # 2 # followed by 1 or more any character including newline
    (?=## \[\d)             # positive lookahead, make sure we have ## [digit after (previous relaese)
/                       # regex delimiter
```

If this regex matches, then print what is matched `print$&`

Comment: Thank you for pointing me on perl match one-liner. I search, but didn't found this one. I can't make it as "solution" since the regex doesn't match other possibility (Unreleased can be empty or contain same data as releases, and first release doesn't have ## at the end of the file to match). BUT your answer point lot of information that help me maje the regex work! +1

Answer (score 0):

Ed can do this.

```
#!/bin/sh

cp CHANGELOG.md stack

cat >> extract.ed << EOF
/2017/
.,\$w new-changelog.txt
EOF

cat >> ex2.ed << EOF
/2015/
-1
.,\$d
wq
EOF

ed -s stack < extract.ed
ed -s new-changelog.txt < ex2.ed
rm -v ./extract.ed ./ex2.ed
```

Comment: I'll use the grep in a gitlab-ci.yml for a CI piepline, and really want to make a simple extract string shortest possible. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Your reply is gracious, and appreciated.